# The value in "sym" file disappears when using splayed tables

Tags: kdb

I am using the following line:

```
`:c:/dir/ set .Q.en[`:c:/dir; tablename]
```

Everything is ok if I don't exit KDB, but if I do and then try to load the table using

```
get `dir
```

all the symbol columns are integer. I would really appreciate your help into understanding why this happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to repeat the table name on the l.h.s. of `set`.

Try

```
q)`:c:/dir/tablename/ set .Q.en[`:c:/dir; tablename]
```

This will correctly save table columns in `c:/dir/tablename` subdirectory and place the `sym` file alongside.  Now you should be able to load both your table and the sym file by using the `\l` command or specifying `c:/dir` on the command line when you restart q

```
q c:/dir
```

or

```
q
q)\l c:/dir
```

(no backticks or leading `:`'s in either of those commands)

If you want to use `get` on this table, you will have to load `sym` separately:

```
q)load`:c:/dir/sym
q)get`:c:/dir/tablename/
```

(note the leading `:` in the path specs)

Finally, you may want to take a look at the [rsave](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/filewords/#rsave) command which will save your table without you having to write `tablename` twice.

Comment: I tried your indications still not working. when I load sym and check what is in it I get something like: `g#`sym! 0 1 2 2 3 1 ... etc. instead of the `buy `sell `amzn  and so on. and in the table i have the numbers from above instead of the labels which I tried to save.

Comment: @Alex it looks like you have a left-over sym column of your table in dir.  Try to delete the directory and redo the steps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I realised the issues was at specifying the directories. I had two of them which had the same name as the table and I think I got confused in them. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

.Q.en takes 2 oarams - file handle and table data

Your first param isnt a hsym - should be backtick then colon then path to your db root

Also set takes 2 params -  first in this case should be the path to where you want to save like dir/splayedTableName/